# Similar to pivot - Windows 8.1 Desktop app

Tags: windows-8.1

Is there a control in windows desktop that behaves similarly to the Pivot control on Windows Phone?

Can a Hub control behave like pivot? Or should I just use `ScrollViewer` (but with just scroll viewer it's hard to determine on which page user currently is right?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no equivalent of the `pivot` control in Windows 8.1. The closest thing to is a horizontal `ListView` or `GridView`, but these don't have the same "snap" effect that the `Pivot` does